# Calculate Speed and Bytes Transfer Rate in FTP download Android

Tags: android, ftp, download

I am planning to create an application for downloading a file from FTP server, Below code has working fine with the functionality, But I need to show current speed and transfer rate while downloading a file, Please help me to solve this problem,

```
private boolean downloadSingleFile(String remoteFilePath, File downloadFile) {


        boolean status = false;
        try {
            con = new FTPClient();

            con.setConnectTimeout(5000);

            con.connect(host);

            if (con.login(username, password)) {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                File parentDir = downloadFile.getParentFile();
                if (!parentDir.exists())
                    parentDir.mkdir();
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
                    con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);



                    status = con.retrieveFile(remoteFilePath, outputStream);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());

                } finally {
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        try {
                            outputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    con.logout();
                    con.disconnect();

                }
            } else {
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();

                // delayWait(duration);


            }

        }

        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());


        } catch (Exception e) {


        }
        return status;
    }
```

If i would like to download a more than 5Mb or 50 Mb file this requirement will be useful for the user to know about the current speed of the device , Please help me to finish this issues.

Regards
Priya

Comment: But what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I need to calculate transfer speed every seconds..and bytes downloaded .. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have to display or update to the UI that, Speed kb/s and downloaded bytes per sec. Please help me to finish

Comment: Yes you told that already three times. That does not bring you further. You will have analysed that code. Now tell why you find it difficult to keep an eye on the amount of bytes already downloaded.